# Test item is not in workflow

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

When setting up a basic A/B test on a component using page editor, I received error with the following appearing in the log:

```
Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: Test item is not in workflow
Source: Sitecore.Analytics
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Data.Items.TestDefinitionItem.Start()
   at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.WebEdit.Commands.Testing.StartTest.Run(ClientPipelineArgs args)
```

Attempting to start test created a Multivariate Test Definition Item with empty workflow section in the Test Lab

[image: Attempting to start test created a Multivariate Test Definition Item with empty workflow section in the Test Lab]

I'm thinking that those Workflow fields should have been appropriately set when using the UI on the page editor to create and start the test.

I guess I'll try reflector to find that error message in the binaries and keep digging.

Sitecore Version: 6.5.0 (rev. 120706)

Comment: I think it might be saying the item you want to test is not in a workflow - not the test item :-) Can you confirm that the item you want to test is in a workflow?

Comment: Disturbingly, when setting the workflow for the content item - either raw values or normally - after saving those fields are cleared again. Setting the Workflow field simply won't save.

Comment: Do you have any custom workflows within your solution which could interfere with Analytics one? Another option would be some custom event which deletes workflow settings from an item after saving it. I would also check if "/sitecore/system/Workflows/Analytics Testing Workflow" item has "Initial state" set although it's unlikely to cause problems since your items don't have workflow at all, not just its state.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question, but I just encountered the same thing in 8.1 update 3. In my case it was because the workflow associated with testing (Analytics Testing Workflow, unless you've made your own) had been deleted on my local installation. Restoring it from one of our other servers made the error go away.

Answer (score -1):

In Sitecore 8.1 and above there is a setting which can be turned on to allow the content authors to start test via experience editor.

Please add the below settings either as  patch config file or 
You can edit the value in the config file (Sitecore.ContentTesting.config).

Setting name is “ContentTesting.AlwaysShowTestCandidateNotification”